# Why is Yara Greyjoy calling herself Queen?

Tags: game-of-thrones

I'm watching season 7 and in the latest episode, Jon meets Daenerys. She tells him he can't be king in the north, as there is only one king. My question is, why is everyone saying that Yara will be the Queen of Iron Islands? She has special treatment from Daenerys or she is just ignorant?

EDIT: I rewatched the episode where Yara first meets with Dany, and they say they want the Iron Islands back. Dany seems to accept. That means she will let her be queen of her islands? If so, why she treats her specially?

Comment: As far as Dany letting Yara be queen of the Iron Islands, the way I saw it in the episodes was that, given that Yara promised not to do any more raiding, Dany gets the huge benefit of the Iron Fleet for the low, low price of a few desolate rocks (even the Ironborn aren't very complimentary of their home) not being under her direct control. In theory, yes, there are now two queens, but in practise, if Yara ever pissed Dany off, it's a small matter to send an army (or a dragon) over to re-assert her authority. Also also, Yara and Dany seemed to get along rather well, hence special treatment.

Answer (score 1):

It's a disputed claim between Euron (siding with Cersei) and Yara (siding with Daenerys).

Balon wished her to be Queen, but was aware this might be challenged (and succession is not hereditary but decided by a 'kingsmoot').

There's more (much, much more) detail in the GoT Wiki: http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Game_of_Thrones_Wiki

Comment: Yes, but why doesn’t Daenerys view Yara’s independence as a threat to her own rule (as she does with Cersei and Jon, say)?

Comment: I believe it is because Yara entered into a pact recognizing Daenerys.